# Signum Function not accepting Negative Values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, math

The following code does not work on negative values:

```
signum n | n < 0 = -1
         | n == 0 =0
         | otherwise = 1
```

Whilst calling `signum -1`. The error it returns is this:

```
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: You the parser interprets this as `signum - 1` (or `(-) signum 1`, the binary operator `(-)` applied to the arguments `signum` and `1`), if you want to pass in negative numbers as arguments you have to parenthesisze: `signum (-1)` or enable [Negative Literals](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/negative_literals.html)